# How can I "reboot" my Clipboard so I can copy/paste between host and RDP again?

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

So basically, from time to time, copy/paste between by host (Windows 10 Pro) and my RDP connected host - stops working.

This is not a case of "remember to enable Clipboard in your RDP settings". It works - most of the time - but sometimes, for reasons I cannot figure out, it stops working.

I've searched around, and the only seemingly valid tips I've found involve resetting the RDPCLIP.EXE. Via Task Manager or Command Line. Like so:

```
Taskkill.exe /im rdpclip.exe
rdpclip.exe
```

Source: [Copy and Paste is not working on my Remote Desktop Connection… what’s wrong?](https://techtalk.gfi.com/copy-paste-working-remote-desktop-connection-whats-wrong/)

Problem is, there is no such thing as `rdpclip.exe` on Windows 10. So what would be my alternative way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try launching **rdpclip.exe** using the command

```
C:\Windows\System32\rdpclip.exe
```

I checked on my Windows 10, it is present at given location. Use `sfc /SCANNOW` if you think it could be missing due to damaged Windows installation.

Comment: Right you are. It wasn't listed in my process list, so I assumed Windows 10 had something different here. I tried starting it and it made no difference. But then I tried reconnecting via RDP (which I had tried before, without any change) - and NOW copy/paste works again. Thank you :-)

Comment: i have similar problem with rdp clipboard, tell me please where do you restart RDPclip.exe on host on guest or both?